# How to convert xml of a pcap type (PDML) to json and print it in proper format

Tags: ruby, xml, json, pcap

1. Is their any way to convert xml to json and vice versa for xml of type pcap?
2. The `to_json` does convert it, but the whole output gets printed in one line. How can I get properly formatted output?

Comment: Did you do `p`, not `puts`? You can even try `require "pp"; pp foo`.

Comment: ok i wil try according to u

Answer (score 0):

You could use the http://cobravsmongoose.rubyforge.org library to do just that. Here's a simple example based on the code from the link above:

```
require 'cobravsmongoose'
xml = '<pdml><packet><proto name="geninfo" pos="1" showname="General information" size="74">...' # PDML document contents
json = CobraVsMongoose.xml_to_json(xml)
# => "pdml":{"packet":{"proto":[{"@name":"geninfo","@pos":"1","@showname":"General information","@size":"74",...
```

I used the ICMP example at http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/.vhost/analyzer.polito.it/30alpha/docs/dissectors/PDMLSpec.htm for testing the conversion above.

To address the comment to the original question about how to pretty print the output, you can use the `#pretty_generate` method in the JSON library to do that:

```
require 'json'
pretty_json = JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse json) # same json as above
puts json
```

Comment: @raza – The library mentioned also has that. From the linked page they give this example: `CobraVsMongoose.json_to_xml(json)`